# Is syncronous document.createlement for html tags?

Tags: javascript

I have some code to create a html UI.
I create divs, imgs, etc. Also, I add code for events.
Basically my code is something like : (pseudo code)

```
for x =1 to n items
{
switch type of tag (div, img, etc)
my_object =document.create(tag);
do some things with my_object
}
```

Ok. So far, my code runs right, but I have a terrible doubt.... 
Is it possible that under certain unknown conditions , 'my_object' isn't created and was not be ready to use at 'do some things with my_object' ??
The same question when I was setting style properties.

In other words, can I expect a sync execution of 'document.create' and 'my_object.style'  settings ? Repeat, so far I have not problems but ....
Thanks.

EDITED : YES, I wanted to write createlement

Comment: Yes you can. in that way everything will be syncronous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering there is no `document.create` it probably doesn't matter if it's synchronous or not.

If however you're using `document.createElement`, yes it's synchronous, and the element will exist, but not in the DOM, you have to actually insert it in the DOM first, and that would be synchronous as well.

As a general rule, most javascript methods are synchronous as there is only one thread, with a few exceptions, like XMLHttpRequest, setInterval, setTimeout, workers etc.

Comment: @ArunKumar - Yes, it's probably a typo, that's why I assumed it was really `createElement`

Comment: And what about document.getelementbyid ? (of course to get or not an existing object in DOM)??? Is it synchro?

Comment: JavaScript/DOM methods are by default synchronous - there's no point in asking about individual ones. If documentation doesn't state otherwise - it's synchronous. If method returns simple object (eg not Promise) and do not accept any callbacks - it has to be synchronous. If a method works synchronously once, it won't start to be asynchronous under the same conditions.